# How to locate the problem row while using insert into select syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, insert

It is a SQL Server procedure. Some error happens while using `insert into xxxx select xxx from` syntax. There are around thousands of rows in this action. Some field in one row in this batch is too long for the table's column capacity. So, the whole action just stopped and rolled back without telling which row is not suitable.

Is there any way to locate this problem row? I try to use `try catch`, and it doesn't tell the right number.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MigratePriceHistory]
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        insert into xxxxx select xxx from xxx
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        PRINT ERROR_NUMBER()
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: You can't trap this with error handling. Is the query selecting from a single table or a more complicated query? You'll need to check the data types of each varchar field of the source/destination and eliminate all columns except candidate ones from your query and examine the data of each. SQL 2019 fixes this btw (at last).

Comment: @Stu. Thanks. What do you mean by SQL2019 fixes this?

Comment: Well, for the purpose of debugging (and only for that -- once the issue is rectified turn back to the set based approach!) you could rewrite the set based `INSERT ... SELECT ...` to loop over a cursor of the `SELECT` and `INSERT` row by row. Print out some ID to identify the row(s) that cause(s) an error.

Comment: `select xxx into #temp from xxx` and check the `max_length`, `precision`, `scale` etc of the temp table against your table. Once you know which column(s), finding the problem row is easy.

Comment: @RobinSun by fix, I mean it actually tells you [which column and what the data is](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/new-truncation-error-message-in-sql-server-2019.html)

Comment: Why don't you just use `LEFT()` or `LEN()`